# Error when checking if object value exists at index in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an object that contains functions which return strings:

```
const values: { [key: string]: () => string } = {
    a: () => 'a',
    b: () => 'b'
};
```

I have a function which looks up a value in the object with the key given as a parameter. I then conditionally do something if the value exists:

```
function foo(key: string) {
    const value = values[key];

    if (value) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

TypeScript gives me an error when checking if the value exists: `This condition will always return true since this function is always defined. Did you mean to call it instead?` [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwDYFcCmEBcMDeMDaA1mgJ7bQBOAlmAOYC62AFAJQwC8AfDJTbTAF8OuAFABIBMzZcYAcgSyANOIBGUjt1krZIgQG4RIgGYowwKFXAwjIEE2JkeUanTY5xoSLESo0wn%20gQRKT0BuJURjBMAWhu4mIA9AkwACIgPCAAtmhQABZ84gK6IkA)

What can I do to resolve this error? Why does TypeScript not warn me if I try to call `value()` without first checking if it exists?

Comment: its making sure you want to invoke it or not. change your `values` type to look like `{ [key: string]: (() => string) | undefined }` indicating there's holes

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` operator to check if the key exists in the `values` object:

```
function foo(key: string) {
    if (key in values) {
        const value = values[key];
        // Do something
    }
}
```

This will also resolve the TypeScript error because the `in` operator checks for the existence of the key without actually accessing the value.

The reason TypeScript does not warn you if you try to call `value()` without first checking if it exists is because the `values` object is declared to have a type of `{ [key: string]: () => string }`, meaning any key of type `string` can exist in the object and the value associated with that key will be a `() => string` function. In this case, TypeScript assumes that the key exists and the value will always be a function.

note: If you are using strict mode, then the error is likely caused by the unused parameter (`value` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Define the properties of `values` as optional:

```js
const values: { [key: string]: () => string } = {
    a?: () => 'a',
    b?: () => 'b'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Object.hasOwnProperty`:

```js
const values: { [key: string]: () => string } = {
    a: () => 'a',
    b: () => 'b'
};

function foo(key: string) {
    if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const value = values[key];
        // Do something
    }
}
```